# VS Web Test receiving 415 against ASP.NET Core API

Tags: visual-studio, web-testing

I've been testing my API (ASP.NET Core 2.1) using Postman with no issues.  I wanted to spin up a load test and I can't get past step one of my load test, receiving a 415 no matter what I try.  When I take the request details and plug it into Postman, the request works fine.

Web test request details:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host : dev.api.chat.users.com
Content-Type : application/json
X-ConsumerId : D8493DB5-E231-E811-80C2-00155DC33B49
Accept-Encoding : GZIP
Accept : */*
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Language : en-US
Content-Length : 46
Connection : Keep-Alive
Expect : 100-continue
{ "username": "loadTestUser-PcRy6an M3as" }
```

Postman (working):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.api.chat.users.com
Content-Type: application/json
X-ConsumerId: D8493DB5-E231-E811-80C2-00155DC33B49
Accept-Encoding: GZIP
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 46
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-continue
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e1dc56bb-1828-41ec-b920-6f53fbc7e84d
{ "username": "loadTestUser-PcRy6an M3as" }------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Not sure why Postman throws on that border as it's not a multi-part, but I doubt that's an issue since it works in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a short-lived issue.  Luckily, I had App Insights on and tracing. Looking at that, I found that the web test was NOT sending content-type application/json, but text/xml.  I had to go to the "String Body" node of the web test and manually set the Content Type in the Properties window to application/json.

Comment: Item 6 of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182557.aspx is the only place I have found any mention of this field in the string body. That item merely says to set the content type to `text/xml` but does not. It seems that the content type of the request is (silently) ignored and the value is taken from the string body.

Comment: Yup, that's what I found.  Annoying little gotchya.

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving 415 error when invoking Get api. After many attempts and experiments I figured out that if I remove CancellationToken from the list of parameters I will have it resolved.

BROKEN (415 status code received):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase 
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResult>> GetAsync(string id, CancellationToken token)
    ...
```

FIXED LINE:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResult>> GetAsync(string id)
```

Now why it happens I don't know. The issues I got was in ASP.NET Core 2.2.7 with Kestrel server.